# What world records were awarded to the TrackMania series by the Guinness World Records?

Tags: trackmania-forever

I read on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrackMania#Reception:

> Due to the success of the TrackMania series, Guinness World Records
>   awarded the games six world records in the Guinness World Records:
>   Gamer's Edition 2008. These include "Biggest Online Race", "Most
>   Popular Online Racing Sim" and "Largest Content Base of Any Racing
>   Game", with hundreds of thousands of user created tracks and hundreds
>   of unique cars available for download.

I don't have access to the book *Guinness World Records: > Gamer's Edition 2008*. What were those six world records and to which games of the TrackMania series were they awarded?

Answer (score 2):

I am hunting them down 1 by 1.  The first one was achieved by having a 250 player race on one track in TM Forever.  Seen Here:

[-Track Mania IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2008/07/02/trackmania-breaks-a-world-record)

The next one I found was for TM Nations - "First publicly available game developed for an online competition."

-[Guinness World Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/first-publicly-available-game-developed-for-an-online-competition)

Another For - "Largest content base of any racing game The TrackMania Exchange"

-[Game Industry Biz](http://www.gamesindustry.biz/articles/trackmania-united-forever-latest-incarnation-of-record-breaking-racer-arrives-next-month)

And that is where I hit my dead-end.  The Guinness site has all of the records, but their Search function pulls a lot for "Track" Records... Meh.  I hope these few are alright for now.  Hopefully someone finds the rest.